# Can we bring back the question about Gauss-Legendre nodes and weights?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, undelete-request

The question

[Computing Gauss Legendre Quadrature for Large N](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203863)

was voluntarily removed by its author, after I implied (with a link to Wikipedia) that the answer was trivial and well-known.  I have since discovered that the answer is non-trivial, highly interesting, and the subject of a very recent paper.  Is it possible to undelete the question?

I would message the author, but I can't find his/her name.

Comment: Just comment somewhere where they'd be notified, and it is not too intrusive, such as http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2235/numerical-analysis-so-vs-mo I am rather against arbitrarily undoing self-deletions (even though the current case seems relatively non-problematic).

Comment: I have left a comment at that post linking to this meta post. The author seems to tune into MO with some regularity, and so should see this note soon.

Comment: @quid Thanks, but I don't know where to comment since I cannot see (and don't recall) who the author is.  I am indeed hoping the author will see this and undo it.

Comment: Yes, I understood this as a possibility, which is why I gave you a link where you could comment (perhaps I did not make this quite clear though, sorry about that). OP of the meta post I linked, is OP of the question you linked.

Comment: Well, I'm curious to know more - it's open to the public again.

Comment: Would you not close it, if it was found out that the answer is on Wiki?